# How to fix this in git "This branch is out-of-date with the base branch"?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project and I made a PR to the project in github and now my PR says that

> "This branch is out-of-date with the base branch , Merge the latest changes from master into this branch"

So which git command should I use in order to make my branch parallel to the master branch?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**If you created the Pull Request from a branch in the same project repository, then:**

- make sure you've checked out your branch (the one from the PR): `git checkout your-branch`
- with your branch checked out, you should do a `git pull origin master`
- then `git push origin your-branch` to update the PR.

**If you forked a repo, created a branch and submit the PR, follow these steps:**

- create a remote with the original project repo: `git remote add upstream 'url.git.here'`
- make sure you've checked out your branch: `git checkout your-branch`
- get the latest changes from the upstream to your-branch: `git pull upstream master`
- after that, push the changes you've got from upstream: `git push origin your-branch`
- finally, you can go to GitHub page to make sure no more `out-of-date` is blocking your PR.

After that, you should see that your PR is all good to be merge (after reviews is set).

Comment: Is there a github setting as well ?

Comment: Yes therer is a Github setting that "Requires branches to be up to date before merging". That causes such warnings. So if you do not want see this warning, you can disable that setting. There are also tools out there that can automatically updated your Github branches. One I've used in past is called mergequeue.com. That tool also supports functionality to keep all branches up to date when a PR is merged